# Pandas group three variables and calculate mean, mode, and median

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
     SCORE ZIP CODE  DATE
0     95.2    90210  2016-01-01
1    98.36    70024  2019-03-02
2     78.2    34567  2017-09-01
3    99.25    00345  2018-05-02
4    .....    .....  .....
```

For each ZIP CODE, I need to calculate the mean, mode, and median, of the SCORE per each year in the DATE column.

How can I do that?

Comment: `df.groupby([df.DATE.dt.year, 'ZIP CODE'])['SCORE'].agg(['min', 'mode', 'median'])`.

Comment: @QuangHoang I get this: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DATE'`

Comment: Isn't `DATE` the column name showed in your sample data? replace `df.DATE` with `df['actual date column name']`. Also make sure it has `datetime` type with `pd.to_datetime`.

Comment: @QuangHoang, it works but I get an error saying that GroupBy has no attribute 'mode'

Comment: @QuangHoang solved by adding a lambda function for the mode.